# nginx alternative for proxy_pass directive within if statement

Tags: if-statement, nginx, configuration, proxypass

I've got the following NGINX configuration:

```
- location /concepts {
  auth_basic "off";
  if ($http_accept ~ 'application/json') { set $isapirequest "true"; }
  if ($http_accept ~ 'application/ld\+json') { set $isapirequest "true"; }
  if ($http_accept ~ 'application/hal\+json') { set $isapirequest "true"; }
  if ( $isapirequest = "true" ) { proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5315/search/concepts/; }
  if ( $isapirequest != "true" ) {
  rewrite ^/concepts$ /concepts/ redirect;
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /blah$1 last;
  }
  include add_cors_headers_OPTIONS_HEAD_GET_PUT_DELETE;
  }
```

The error that I'm getting is:

```
\"proxy_pass\" cannot have URI part in location given by regular expression, or inside named location, or inside \"if\" statement, or inside \"limit_except\"
```

Can you guys think of any way on NGINX to achieve the above without using an "if" statement?

Comment: Use a `rewrite...last` instead, and handle the `proxy_pass` in a different `location` block.

Comment: @Richard Smith, I've just updated my question - sorry about that. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last two `if` statements are mutually exclusive, so one of them can be eliminated, which would remove the error you are getting.

[This document](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) indicates which statements should be used inside an `if` block within a `location` context. You might consider using a `map` to replace all but one of the `if` statements.

For example:

```
map $http_accept $redirect {
    default                 1;
    ~application/json       0;
    ~application/ld\+json   0;
    ~application/hal\+json  0;
}

server {
    ...
    location /concepts {
        auth_basic "off";

        if ($redirect) {
            rewrite ^(.*)$ /blah$1 last;
        }
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5315/search/concepts;
        include add_cors_headers_OPTIONS_HEAD_GET_PUT_DELETE;
    }
    ...
}
```

The `rewrite ^/concepts$ /concepts/ redirect;` statement can be moved to the `location` that processes the `/blah/concepts` URI, and rewritten as `rewrite ^/blah/concepts$ /concepts/ redirect;`.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) for more.